# I wanted to draw on a Canvas which is on top of another control and also able to access the control, is this possible in HTML?

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I have an use case to draw lines/shapes using Canvas or SVG APIs, These graphics will be drawn on a layer which is on top of a set of controls. The issue I have now is, Once the Canvas is placed on top of the controls, I am not able to access the controls, like clicking on a checkbox/button etc.  How can I enable this ?

eg

```
<div>
   <div id="layer1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:10px">
         <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
    <canvas id="layer2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:10px"></canvas>
</div>
```

In the above sample, I am not able to click on the "submit" button because of the layer on top, What I wanted to do is to draw circle around the button, same time I should be able to click on the button as well.

Is this possible in HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you can't click "through" HTML elments, but you still have a lot of options.

One very quick solution is to use `pointer-events: none;` in your style code for the canvas.

This will work on Firefox/chrome/safari, but not IE.

For IE you'll have to get more clever.

...But why not just put the button on top instead of having the canvas on top? A quick way to do this is to give the canvas `z-index: -1;` in its style.

So all together now:

```
<div>
   <div id="layer1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:10px">
         <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
    <canvas id="layer2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:10px; border: 1px solid black; pointer-events: none; z-index: -1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Why I need canvas on top is because when I make any drawing It should be visible on top of the existing elements, eg, a Scrollbar, I should be able to draw a line on top of the scrollbar, if I put canvas below the lines will go behind the scrollbar.

Comment: I was trying your solution with SVG (RaphaelJs). Will I be able to add events to the "svg" path to enable stroke selection ? i.e, I should be able to click on the button, same time I should be able to select the stroke also (i wanted to select, delete the circle/line and draw another line on top of the controls)

Comment: Yes, with RaphaelJs you should be able to add events to any svg paths you create and treat them as if they were objects. Now that I think about it, svg would probably be much better than canvas for the particular thing you want to do.